# Webflux - Spring Boot - oAuth2 client with http proxy support

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-oauth2

I'm struggeling to correctly setup the webflux-weblient with oauth2 behind a proxy.

It seems, that the ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction uses a new instance of a webclient , which doesn't contain my proxy-configuration.

**OAuth2-Config**

```
    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2ClientFilter = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
      clientRegistrations,
      new UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository());
   oauth2ClientFilter.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("azure");
```

OAuth2AuthorizedClientResolver.class contains:

```
private ReactiveOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequest> clientCredentialsTokenResponseClient = new WebClientReactiveClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient();
```

The `WebClientReactiveClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient.java` creates a new webclient as follows:

`private WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().build();`

Does anybody have a sample how to correctly setup a http-proxy for the oauth2 client?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Have you tried the solution mentioned by @jocker ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the incomplete answer of @abhinaba-chakraborty, I managed to set proxy based on the JVM params inside the `WebClient` for `WebClientReactiveClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient`.

Here is my pieces of code to help other people with the same issue :

This is a helper function to take the JVM params and set them to the HttpClient

```java
    public HttpClient proxyHttpClient() {
        String proxyHost = System.getProperty("https.proxyHost");
        String proxyPort = System.getProperty("https.proxyPort");

        if (proxyHost == null && proxyPort == null) {
            return HttpClient.create();
        }

        return HttpClient.create()
                .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient ->
                        tcpClient.proxy(proxy ->
                                proxy.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP).host(proxyHost).port(Integer.valueOf(proxyPort))
                        )
                );
    }
```

This is how to configure the OAuth2Client for the `WebClient` used for calling outside systems (based on the response of @abhinaba-chakraborty). Note the function named `configureHttpProxy`:

```java
    @Bean
    public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {

        return configureHttpProxy(
                new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                        clientRegistrationRepository,
                        authorizedClientService
                )
        );
    }

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("registration_id");
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth2Client)
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create().wiretap(true)))
                .baseUrl(rdoWebClientProperties.getBaseUrl())
                .defaultHeader(rdoWebClientProperties.getApikeyName(), rdoWebClientProperties.getApikeyValue())
                .build();
    }
```

And here is the `configureHttpProxy` function:

```java
    private AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager configureHttpProxy(AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        // set the webclient with proxy configuration in the ReactiveOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient
        WebClientReactiveClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient tokenResponseClient = new WebClientReactiveClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient();
        tokenResponseClient.setWebClient(
                WebClient.builder()
                        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(proxyHttpClient()))
                        .build()
        );

        // set the ReactiveOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient with webclient configuration in the ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider
        ClientCredentialsReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = new ClientCredentialsReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider();
        authorizedClientProvider.setAccessTokenResponseClient(tokenResponseClient);

        // set the ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider in the ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
```

Hoping this will help.

Comment: You are a lifesaver, thank you! I had to set the proxy http client when building the webclient as well to make it work (where you have used HttpClient.create().wiretap(true)).

Answer (score 0):

For OAuth2.0 Client Credentials flow, in the websecurity configuration, you need something like:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
      ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
      ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {

    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
            .clientCredentials()
            .build();

    AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
        new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
            clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

    return authorizedClientManager;
  }
  @Bean
  public WebClient webClient(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
    return WebClient.builder().filter(oauth).build();
  }
}
```

Now to make an actual API call:

```
webClient.get()
        .uri(<protected resource uri which you want to access>)
        .attributes(clientRegistrationId(<The Provider name specified under registration in app yaml>))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .map(string
            -> "Retrieved using Client Credentials Grant Type: " + string)
        .subscribe(LOGGER::info);
```

For your reference I am using the Spring Boot version 2.3.1.RELEASE
And my application.yaml looks like this:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          <provider-name>:
            issuer-uri: <issuer-uri implementing OIDC>
        registration:
          <provider-name>:
            client-id: <client-id>
            client-secret: <client-secret>
            scope: <comma separated scopes>
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
```

Comment: Thx but I can't see any proxy configuration in your sample... That's, as mentioned in the question, is the issue here...